# CMPXCHG and critical section implementation

Tags: c, concurrency, parallel-processing, critical-section, test-and-set

The CMPXCHG statement works as follows:

```
CMPXCHG (common, old, new):
    int temp
    temp <- common
    if common = old then
           common <- new
    return temp
```

What is the simplest possible algorithm for implementing a
critical section, if a CMPXCHG atomic instruction is available?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a simple critical section (using the [Windows definition of a `CRITICAL_SECTION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530(v=vs.85).aspx)), you can look at the following pseduo-code:

```
EnterCS(cs):
    If CMPXCHG(cs,0,1) = 0 
        Return True
    Return False

ExitCS:
    If CMPXCHG(cs,1,0) = 1 
        Return True
    Return False
```

Then using it becomes a simple case of:

```
If EnterCS(cs)
    SomeValue <- SomeValue + 10 
    ExitCS(cs)
```

This acquisition is actually more like a try-to-acquire, to extend to to the more common acquisition scheme of CS's, we alter the method like so

```
EnterCS(cs):
    While CMPXCHG(cs,0,1) != 0
        SpinOneCycle()
    Return True
```

This simple lock has its various issues, such as the inability to handle recursion, for which you need to keep a recursive lock count. I would recommend using something provided by the operating system. If you do need to write your own locks, 
Intel has a few publications on writing high-performance and scalable spinlocks, you can read one of them for Xeon processors [here](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/xeon-lock-scaling-analysis-paper.pdf) and another for x86 [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/implementing-scalable-atomic-locks-for-multi-core-intel-em64t-and-ia32-architectures/). Lockless Inc also has an article on spinlocks [here](https://locklessinc.com/articles/locks/).